# Ubuntu on laptop Yoga 9 14AP7

Tags: lenovo

Im now about to install Ubuntu as 2nd OS on my laptop Yoga 9 14AP7. Have smbd experience? The question is how will work touch screen, pen, etc..

This gonna be my first Linux.

Comment: Questions about how Ubuntu works on particular devices is asking for off-topic opinions, which are best suited to Forums. This is a Q&A site where the question is the *problem* that needs to be solved & answers are methods to solve the asked problem. https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: ok. thank you. will check forums as well.

Comment: The simple thing you can do is check it will work in a live usb session. If it does, it’s very likely it will work if you install.